# API2_query CPANEL Email listing output format - xmlapi

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I used the following code 
PHP Code:

```
include '../xmlapi.php'; 

$ip = 'ip'; 
$root_pass = 'pwd'; 

$account = "acc"; 

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip); 
$xmlapi->password_auth($account,$root_pass); 
$xmlapi->set_output("json"); 
$xmlapi->set_port(2082); 
$xmlapi->set_debug(1); 
$output = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "listpopswithdisk" ); 
print $output;
```

The output was in 
such a format
{"cpanelresult":{"apiversion":2,"preevent":{"result":1},"data":[{"mtime":1411037171,"diskquota":"unlimited","_diskused":"54

I want the output to be in a table. Can anyone suggest 
how can I do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this

First decode jason to Array

```
include '../xmlapi.php'; 

$ip = 'ip'; 
$root_pass = 'pwd'; 

$account = "acc"; 

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip); 
$xmlapi->password_auth($account,$root_pass); 
$xmlapi->set_output("json"); 
$xmlapi->set_port(2082); 
$xmlapi->set_debug(1); 
$output = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "listpopswithdisk" ); 
$output = json_decode($output)
print_r($output);
```

Second is getting output in Array instead of jason

```
include '../xmlapi.php'; 

$ip = 'ip'; 
$root_pass = 'pwd'; 

$account = "acc"; 

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip); 
$xmlapi->password_auth($account,$root_pass); 
$xmlapi->set_output("array"); 
$xmlapi->set_port(2082); 
$xmlapi->set_debug(1); 
$output = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "listpopswithdisk" ); 
print $output;
```

Now you can print table from this array using foreach loop

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($output as $key => $value){ 
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' . $key . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
 }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I was doing the same silly mistake. Thank you saved me.